# Rendering backbone collection from JSON file not completely working

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, collections, mustache

I have searched high and low for an answer that explains why app is not rendering my list collection from my JSON file but I just cannot figure this out..

So all i am trying to do is render a list from my JSON file - pretty simple but it just isn't working..

Would really appreciate any help. I have posted my code and put a version on a [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/eYIraYi/1/edit?html,js,output).

Running the code through the console, I can see the json data in the DOM but I just don't see any data.

Thanks!

App.js:

```
    // MODELS
    var EventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.on('change', function() {
                eventView.render();
            });
        },
        defaults: {
            "name": "No title entered",
            "description": "No description entered",
            "startdate": "No start date"
        }
    });
    var eventModel = new EventModel();

    // COLLECTIONS
    var EventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: EventModel,
        url: 'data/getEvents.json',
        initialize: function() {
            this.on('reset', function() {
                eventListView.render();
            }),
            console.log('running init function for EventCollection');
            this.fetch({async: false});
            console.log(this.toJSON()); //This will log the loaded collection
        },
        parse: function(data) {
            console.log('running parse');
            return _.map(data, _.identity);
        },
        reset: function(models, options) {
            if (options && options.parse) {
                delete options.parse;
                models = this.parse(models);
            }
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.reset.call(this, models, options);
        }
    });
    var eventCollection = new EventCollection();


    // VIEWS
    var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'single-model',
        render: function() {
            var el = this.el;
            $(el).html(Mustache.render($('#stream_getEvents').text()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var EventListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#list'),
        tagName: 'ul',
        id: 'list-view',
        initalize: function() {
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
            this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.addAll();
        },
        addOne: function(eventModel) {
            var eventView = new EventView({model: eventModel});
            this.$el.append(eventView.render().el);
        },
        addAll: function() {
            this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        }
    });


    // rendering
    var eventView = new EventView({model: eventModel});
    var eventListView = new EventListView({collection: eventCollection});


    function event(){
        eventView.render();
        eventListView.render();
        $('#list').html(eventListView.$el.html());
        console.log('clicked button');
    }

    $('.button-getEvents').click(event);
```

Comment: What do you get if you print to console the collection in your event function. Try inserting `console.log(eventCollection);` as first line of `function event()`

Comment: Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...} - that's what it prints out.. the json url is http://bkretail.co.za/wp-content/themes/bk/getEvents.json (missing .../mpl/getEvents.json).

Comment: new - http://jsbin.com/eYIraYi/10/edit?html,js,output... I notice that running my local version i see the data in the console, but through my js bin I see nothing in the console..

Comment: Yes jsbin is throwing a domain access error 'No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"...' which in short means it can't access your domains data.

Comment: Assuming your data request is good.  Have you tried tracing through EventListView to see what is actually happening... put console.log at beginning of each function (render, addOne, addAll etc.) to see if the view is trying to render the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the model from the mustache template rendering.

```
$(el).html(Mustache.render($('#stream_getEvents').text(), this.model));
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I did add the modal to the template rendering (whoops silly mistake) but I still cannot see the data.. No errors in the console either..

Comment: It's hard to tell as your jsbin reports 404 errors when retrieving getEvents.json.  Presumably getEvents.json is in the correct format?